# How to derive keys (HKDF) from two EC key pairs in Dart/Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, cryptography, ecdh, hkdf

I'm currently implementing ISO 18013-5 (mobile driving license) using Dart and Flutter (sorry, can't share the full specification document). Briefly, in order to prevent eavesdropping during a data exchange between a reader (e.g. Police) and a citizen, two ephemeral keys (`EDeviceKey` and `EReaderKey`) are generated (using ECDH), one in each device. After, the public keys are exchanged to create one Session Key per device (`skDevice` and `skReader`). These keys are derived using ECKA-DH (as defined in BSI TR-03111).

In order to explain my struggle, lets focus on one application, the citizen: To derive the session key, I need to use HKDF, with the citizen's private key and the reader's public key. For that I have the following:

```dart
Future<SimpleKeyPair> generateEDeviceKeyPair() async {
  final algorithm = Ecdh.p256(length: 256);

  final keyPair = await algorithm.newKeyPair();

  return keyPair;
}

// The public key will be generated on the reader application, using this method
Future<EcKeyPair> generateEReaderKeyPair() async {
  final algorithm = Ecdh.p256(length: 256);

  final keyPair = await algorithm.newKeyPair();

  return keyPair;
}

Future<SecretKey> generateSKDevice(EcKeyPairData eDeviceKeyPriv, EcKeyPublic eReaderKeyPub) async {
  final zAB = null;
  final algorithm = Hkdf(
    hmac: Hmac(Sha256()),
    outputLength: 32,
  );

  // HOW TO "MERGE" BOTH KEYS?
  final secretKey = eDeviceKeyPriv + eReaderKeyPub // ??

  final output = await algorithm.deriveKey(secretKey: secretKey, info: utf8.encode("SKDevice"));

  return output;
}
```

Then, to use the Session Key to encrypt the data:

```dart
Future<List<int>> encryptMDocResponse(Object mdocResponse, SecretKey skDevice) async {
  final algorithm = AesGcm.with256bits();

  // Encrypt
  final secretBox = await algorithm.encrypt(
    utf8.encode(json.encode(mdocResponse)),
    secretKey: skDevice
  );

  return secretBox.cipherText;
}
```

The problem lies in the `generateSKDevice` method. It has to receive the private key from the citizen (`eDeviceKeyPriv`) and the public key from the reader (`eReaderKeyPub`). My question is: how to merge both keys in order to derive one, using the `deriveKey` method (crypto lib: https://pub.dev/packages/cryptography)? Making the parallel to Javascript, I could use the `crypto.subtle.deriveKey` method.

Since this is my first time working with cryptography, I hope this isn't a dummy question.

Thank you in advance!

EDIT:

```dart
import 'package:cryptography/cryptography.dart';
import 'dart:convert';

Object getMDoc() {
  return {
    "test": "test",
    "test2": {"a": "b"},
    "test3": 3
  };
}

Future<SimpleKeyPair> generateEDeviceKeyPair() async {
  final algorithm = X25519();

  final keyPair = await algorithm.newKeyPair();

  return keyPair;
}

// Changed algorithm to X25519
Future<SimpleKeyPair> generateEReaderKeyPair() async {
  final algorithm = X25519();

  final keyPair = await algorithm.newKeyPair();

  return keyPair;
}

// Generated a sharedSecretKey to derive the session key
Future<SecretKey> generateSKDevice(
    SimpleKeyPairData eDeviceKeyPriv, SimplePublicKey eReaderKeyPub) async {
  final algorithm = X25519();

  final sharedSecretKey = await algorithm.sharedSecretKey(
      keyPair: eDeviceKeyPriv, remotePublicKey: eReaderKeyPub);

  final deriveAlgorithm = Hkdf(
    hmac: Hmac(Sha256()),
    outputLength: 32,
  );

  final skDevice = await deriveAlgorithm.deriveKey(
      secretKey: sharedSecretKey,
      info: utf8.encode("SKDevice"),
      nonce: <int>[1, 2]);

  return skDevice;
}

Future<SecretKey> generateSKReader(
    SimpleKeyPairData eReaderKeyPriv, SimplePublicKey eDeviceKeyPub) async {
  // final algorithm = Ecdh.p256(length: 256);
  final algorithm = X25519();

  final sharedSecret = await algorithm.sharedSecretKey(
      keyPair: eReaderKeyPriv, remotePublicKey: eDeviceKeyPub);

  final deriveAlgorithm = Hkdf(
    hmac: Hmac(Sha256()),
    outputLength: 32,
  );

  final output = await deriveAlgorithm.deriveKey(
      secretKey: sharedSecret,
      info: utf8.encode("SKReader"),
      nonce: <int>[1, 2]);

  return output;
}

Future<SecretBox> encryptMDocResponse(
    Object mdocResponse, SecretKey skDevice) async {
  final algorithm = AesGcm.with256bits();

  final secretBox = await algorithm.encrypt(
    utf8.encode(json.encode(mdocResponse)),
    secretKey: skDevice,
  );

  return secretBox;
}

Future<List<int>> decryptMDocResponse(
    SecretBox mdocResponse, SecretKey skReader) async {
  final algorithm = AesGcm.with256bits();

  final chipherText = await algorithm.decrypt(
    mdocResponse,
    secretKey: skReader,
  );

  return chipherText;
}

// Example of use
Future<void> main(List<String> arguments) async {
  // Holder: get mdoc
  final mdoc = getMDoc();

  // Holder & Reader: generate Ephemeral Keys
  final eDeviceKey = await generateEDeviceKeyPair();
  final eReaderKey = await generateEReaderKeyPair();

  // Holder: generate Session Key (skDevice)
  final skDevice = await generateSKDevice(
      await eDeviceKey.extract(), await eReaderKey.extractPublicKey());

  // Holder: encrypt device response
  final response = await encryptMDocResponse(mdoc, skDevice);

  // Reader: generate Session Key (skDevice)
  final skReader = await generateSKReader(
      await eReaderKey.extract(), await eDeviceKey.extractPublicKey());

  // Reader: decrypt device response
  final decrypted = await decryptMDocResponse(response, skReader); // Error here
}
```

Comment: I don't know ISO 18013-5, but I suspect that you have to generate a shared secret with the private and public key (with [`sharedSecretKey()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cryptography/latest/cryptography/KeyExchangeAlgorithm/sharedSecretKey.html)) and the so generated shared secret (of type `SecretKey`) is in turn the input for the HKDF or [`deriveKey()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cryptography/latest/cryptography/Hkdf/deriveKey.html) to derive the final key.

Comment: @Topaco According to this [issue](https://github.com/dint-dev/cryptography/issues/31), "ECDH and ECDSA are supported only in the browser at the moment". Therefore, I changed the key generation algorithm to Ed25519 (which is another supported by the ISO). However, this type of algorithm doesn't have the method ```sharedSecretKey```

Comment: Ed25519 is used for signing (Curve 25519 equivalent to ECDSA), for a key agreement X25519 (Curve 25519 equivalent to ECDH) is required, which also has a [`sharedSecretKey()`](https://pub.dev/documentation/cryptography/latest/cryptography/X25519-class.html) method.

Comment: @Topaco yeah, I noticed that I could use that key agreement and made some changes. Now it's giving ```SecretBox has wrong message authentication code (MAC)``` when trying to decrypt the message (encapsulated in a ```SecretBox```, output of the ```encryptMDocResponse``` method). It's hard for me to debug this `:) . I've updated the original post, with the current code, under 'EDIT'. Sorry for the long post

Comment: The last posted code is incomplete, so no real analysis is possible. Please complete it so that a repro is possible via copy/paste. Did you check if `skDevice` and `skReader` contain the same key?

Comment: @Topaco you should be able to copy/past and reproduce the error

Comment: You use different values for `info` in the `Hkdf#deriveKey()` calls, resulting in different keys. Apply the same value, then it works.

Comment: @Topaco Thank you so much! It works now. According to the ISO, I should use different ```info``` values (as in https://imgur.com/a/ndi8khp). Do you want to answer the question so I can mark it as resolved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed with [Topaco](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9014097/topaco) in the comments:

- First: Had to change the algorithm to `X25519` in order to be supported in mobile devices by Flutter;
- Second: in order to derive the session key, I had to create a `sharedSecret`:

```
final sharedSecret = await algorithm.sharedSecretKey(keyPair: eReaderKeyPriv, remotePublicKey: eDeviceKeyPub);
```

- Third: Use the same `info` parameter across applications

(The remaining code is available in the EDITed section of the original post)